# How to prevent wxWidgets window from blinking in the taskbar when created?

Tags: windows, wxwidgets, taskbar

If my wxWidgets application creates a new window while the application does not have focus, its taskbar icon blinks yellow until I switch to it, as shown here:

[image]

This is annoying.  How can I prevent this from happening?

*EDIT*: The original version of this question suggested the blinking was happening during startup.  After further investigation, this is not occurring right at application startup; rather, it occurs if I create an additional window while the application does not have focus.

To give a bit more background: my application is a sort of server, that opens windows in response to network events.  If I boot up the application, then switch focus to something else and a network event comes in while the focus is elsewhere, my application will open a new window in the background (not grabbing focus) and this blinking will occur.

The windows are `wxFrame`s; the application constructs them and their child widgets, then calls `Show(true)` on the frame.

Also, I've attempted to set a breakpoint on the `FlashWindow` Win32 API function, hoping to trap wherever in WX it's getting called, but haven't been able to make that work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following would work:

wxTopLevelWindow::ShowWithoutActivating (       )

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#a03e526f505716568318d601318527bd0

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't prevent the blinking. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you create a new top level window while the app does not have focus, then the task bar icon will flash.  This is the intended behaviour of the windows operating system.